# iOS UIViewControllerのコンテナビューに追加したUITableViewControllerのビューの上に空白ができる

Tags: ios, uitableview

ViewControllerのコンテナビューにTableViewControllerを追加(segueのEmbedで接続)した所上部にステータスバーとナビゲーションバー分の空白が生じてしまいます。
そういうものかと思いコンテナビューの領域をナビゲーションバーの下の部分までとしていたのをViewControllerのviewを全て覆うように変更しました。
しかし、コンテナビューに別のTableViewControllerのviewを表示させると今度は上部に空白ができず下記写真のようにバーと重なってしまいます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ViewControllerをコンテナビューとして2つのTableViewControllerを切り替えるものを作りたいのですがどのように設定を変更すれば上部に隙間ができないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[ここ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906919/remove-empty-space-before-cells-in-uitableview)の回答を参考にして解決することができました。
コンテナビューコントローラのviewDidLoadで
`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`を設定することで空白を解消することができます。

Comment: `UIViewController`がコンテンツかコンテナかに関わらず、その`view`プロパティか、`view.subviews[0]`が`UITableView`または`UIScrollView`（もしくはその派生クラス）のとき、`contentInset`で上部に余白が設定されます。それを解除する方法は、回答の通りです。